# JButton text truncated if the text length is bigger then the button size

Tags: java, swing, text, jbutton

I have a `JPanel` containing a `JButton` Like The Following Photo:

[image]

The problem is that if I typed a text like `"Test Name"` it is OK because the size of the button is fit!

But if I typed a text like `"Test Name Example"` or any other big text I need it to do like the following if it is possible!

[image]

Note: Code for the button

```
JButton btnfast = new JButton();
btnfast.setSize(120, 120);
btnfast.setMinimumSize(btnfast.getSize());
btnfast.setBackground(Color.white);
btnfast.setForeground(Color.black);
btnfast.setFont(Classes.Setting.fontDef);
btnfast.setText("Test Name Example");
btnfast.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
pd2.FastAddPanal.add(btnfast);
```

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) will show you how to split text on more than one line.

Comment: The source of the problem is in code not shown. After all the components are added, call `pack()` on the frame and it will be the right size.